# converting employee_number into employee_range using case but system throwing error(Error converting data type varchar to bigint)

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, varchar, bigint

Converting Employee_number into employee bins but system is throwing error.

Not sure if it has to do with null values in employee_number; Existing answers are not helpful

Employee_number (bigint - datatype, null values exist, 0 - 7500000 range)

Query:

```
select company_primary_id,
       case when employee_number is null then 'No data'
            when employee_number between 1 and 250 then '1-250' 
            when employee_number between 250 and 1000 then '250 - 1K' 
             else '1K+' end as employee_range
           from Company_table 

Expected Output: Company_primary_id | Employee_range
                  1234                 1-250
                  4532                 1K+
```

> Error: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data would also be helpful.

Comment: Column employee_number data type?

Comment: Tagged the database; employee_number data type is bigint. It has values ranging from 0 to 7500000 and null values;

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I cannot think of any database that could generate that error with this query.  Why?  The only possible conversion taking place is in the comparison of `employee_number` in the `when` clauses.  The `case` properly returns strings in all paths -- and that would be the "normal" reason for this error.

I could imagine the problem if `employee_number` where a string.  But the comparison value would not be treated as a `bigint`, so it is unclear where that error is coming from.

The only other possibility is that `company_table` is really a view and something else entirely is going wrong in the view.

Comment: Table is not a view. employee_number data type is bigint, i am not sure why system is throwing error "Varchar to bigint conversion" when the conversion is other way